# Run exe from within program

Tags: windows

I have been trying to run a small executable from my code with pretty much 0 success. If I place the .exe in the main directory (and the files it needs) it does fine. But that is very messy, as there are several files in there already.

This is the directory I want it in:

```
C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\GSP381 iLab\\GSP381 iLab\\Models\\ModelLoader.exe
```

I have tried using `ShellExecute` and `system("")` as well as `CreateProcess()`. Each time I try to put in the exact file path in, it fails. Same goes for things like `./ModelLoader.exe`, `ModelLoader.exe`, or even `./Models/ModelLoader.exe`.

It is getting to be quite annoying. My research has told me that `system()` is not the way to go, but I am 100% unconcerned with security or runtime, because this is just a learning experience for me. I just want to get something that works right now.

Edit:
Currently I've just commented everything out. It is running only this. As for failing, the program runs, but the executable does not. The executable 100% works. Verified it many times. So that is not the issue.

```
    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pScmdline, int iCmdshow)
    {
        system("ModelLoader.exe");
    }
```

Comment: Define *"it fails"* - do you get an error (which one), does your program crash, ...? Also provide the actual code you tried

Comment: By default, a program executed using `system()` or `CreateProcess()` is in an environment like the parent program (same environment variables, same working directory, etc).   You need to set the environment to suit needs of the spawned program.    With `system()`, you will need to do that before calling `system()`.   `CreateProcess()` provides some options which affect that, but you have to use them.       Also, this question is really a windows programming question, not C++.

Comment: You have spaces in the full path. You need to quote process path when you pass it to any function that expects a *command line*. E. g. `system()` or `CreateProcess()` parameter `lpCommandLine`. When you pass process path to `ShellExecute()` parameter `lpFile` you don't need quotes though.

Comment: I appreciate the help, guys. I ended up going with Jay's suggestion below, as it was a simple matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SetCurrentDirectory`. If the executable depends on local files, then it will be looking for them in the current working directory, where your host program is executing from. Changing the working directory allows the new running program to search for its local files there.

Comment: Don't know who gave you the down vote, but this totally worked. +1 from me since it is simple and to the point. I could have gone about this in a way that is like 100x easier, but I wanted the challenge. I appreciate the help!

Comment: If it works for you, could you accept it as an answer?